# Vectorize this for loop: applying a function to sub-indices?

Tags: r, vectorization

Is there some way to vectorize the following?

```
# x: some vector
# index: some vector of indeces
n <- length(index)
y <- rep(NA, n)
for (i in 1:n) {
  y[i] = myfunction(x[1:index[i])
}
```

Basically, I'd like to apply `myfunction` to various subsets of the vector `x`. It doesn't seem like the `apply` functions are built to handle this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I am not sure if I understand what you are up to, but if you want to get from the `x` vector the first `index`-es number of elements, than make up some sample data:

```
x <- runif(10)
index <- c(2,5,4,8)
```

And try:

```
> lapply(index, function(index) return(x[1:index]))
[[1]]
[1] 0.3869757 0.4060021

[[2]]
[1] 0.3869757 0.4060021 0.4843015 0.2064443 0.4614179

[[3]]
[1] 0.3869757 0.4060021 0.4843015 0.2064443

[[4]]
[1] 0.3869757 0.4060021 0.4843015 0.2064443 0.4614179 0.9278044 0.7351291
[8] 0.9792204
```